# Any way to split a div into a grid, or many divs

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the core components for my next project and I need a way to make a grid with HTML, or JavaScript that will have grid points that are aware of eachother in a sense. My problem right now is I cant figure out how to make the grid in the first place. I have an HTML div 800x800px and I need to sperate it into 50x50px divs, the only problem is if I hardcode it ill need to write and style 256 divs. Is there any way to split this div into those pieces with JavaScript or maybe use canvas animations for it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FindMyKeys</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="background">
            <div id="grid1" class="grid"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    margin:0;
}

#background {
    position:absolute;
    height:800px;
    width:800px;
    background-color:grey;
    top:100px;
    left:540px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you mean by 'aware of eachother' but why dont you use grid CSS property? It seems it is perfect for what you want to do.

If you cannot you can always create a canvas as a wrapper div and then create those 256 divs as absolute position items in the canvas but I am not really fond of this. First you should explain why you cannot use CSS grid really.

Comment: The CSS grid from what I've seen is a way to format your websites which isn't what I want to do, I want to turn a single div into a grid of many grids. If CSS grid can do that for me I'll do it but each section of the grid has to be editable with CSS and JavaScript for me to worry about making them aware of eachother. Basically making them aware of the properties of the other squares in their area.

Comment: funny I am building something like that in my work now and ye you can totally use grid. Look every element in the Grid has a property that says where the item belongs to in the grid. These are row-start, row-end, column-start, column-end. You manipulate these properties via JS! You can off manipulate the grid itself too so you can make it bigger or whatever. Try something on stackblitz and if you struggle I might help you. But you gotta do some working test project first

Comment: @RadekPienký I've got it working but it was a pain giving the ids to each 256 grid points.